# Gist oneboxing does not work when username is included

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, onebox

Gist oneboxing fails to work when the url of the gist is like this:

https://gist.github.com/nathan-osman/4942570

(see [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8094056#8094056))

But they work fine when the url is like this

https://gist.github.com/4942570

(see [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8094232#8094232))

I guess this would be a bug right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed it is!

It's now done and it should be fixed once a new version of the chat is deployed.

Comment: [It appears to be broken.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9097726#9097726)

Comment: It appears to be broken again.  See http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/11489355#11489355 and  http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/11489427#11489427 for some poking at it.