# Gist oneboxing in chat is broken again.

Tags: bug, status-declined, chat, onebox

I attempted to paste a link to a Gist in chat:

https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9098399#9098399

As you can see, neither URL is working, even though they both should:

- [Gist support for chat 'onebox'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57041/gist-support-for-chat-onebox)
- [Gist oneboxing does not work when username is included](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167673/gist-oneboxing-does-not-work-when-username-is-included)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GitHub was 403-ing on us therefore preventing the Gist one-box from functioning. I am not sure there's much we can do in that case :-)

Comment: No way to contact github and ask to allow access somehow? :)

Comment: I guess this should be taken out of the chat FAQ then if it'll never be fixed?