# Oneboxing for MSDN/GitHub

Tags: feature-request, chat, onebox

We have oneboxing for Wikipedia, Twitter, and a few other sites.  It would be nice to have oneboxing for MSDN and GitHub links.

Comment: related for github:http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177532/gist-oneboxing-in-chat-is-broken-again

Comment: @EBrown [Badges](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/262001/269301)

Comment: If you C# people get MSDN, we Java people want Javadoc oneboxes for oracle's official site! :)

Comment: @Vogel612'sShadow Fair enough.

Comment: And iOS people want one-boxing for Apple's docs...