# OneBoxing badges

Tags: feature-request, badges, chat, onebox

I'm not sure if this is the right term, but we can OneBox tags like `[tag:tag-name]` and `[meta-tag:tag-name]`. It would be nice to be able to do this for badges as well.

Comment: And MSDN links.

Comment: @EBrown [MSDN](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/262000/oneboxing-for-msdn-github-badges)

Comment: This is a pretty good idea. In fact, I wondered why I could one-box a hypothetical tag, like [tag:i-really-like-to-know-who-i-should-blame], but [badge:enlightened] didn't do anything. If there's a good argument against this, I would really like to hear it.

Comment: I'd still like to see this happen, but apparently it is a duplicate to an unresolved post from 4 years ago.